# React front-end on AWS EC2?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2

I can't believe how trivial this is, but I can't find any examples where it's not part of a bigger build that just adds further complexity.

I'm putting together a smallish website and while I'm at it, also taking the time to have a play around with some AWS services.

I have a React front-end with no back-end for now, and I'm running it on an EC2 instance. **Before everyone starts going crazy telling me it's overkill for what I need, I know I can use Amplify or S3**, but like I said, I'm having a play around  with something more complex as the project will grow further down the line.

---

**What I want to do...**

Run my React front-end on EC2, with some kind of package management (e.g. Forever or PM2 etc) to keep it running when I close my terminal.

---

**Where I'm at...**

To my understanding, I need to install Node to serve my React front-end (...but I don't think this is right?).

So, I've:

- Installed Node & NPM
- Cloned my repo
- Installed the front-end dependencies
- Created a production build with `npm run build`
- Booted up the front-end with `npm start`
- Watched as my glorious site fills my browser :emotional:

---

**My problem...**

Even though it works, I don't think it's right, and I have an issue.

1) I create the build folder to serve the static files, but still run `npm start` which is a dev build <- ???

2) When I try and add either Forever or PM2, it doesn't work anymore, as in the site cannot be reached

---

- So what am I doing wrong?
- Do I even need Node to only run the front-end?
- Where should the React `build` folder go?
- How do I serve the files?
- How do I keep it running?

---

As I say, it seems so trivial, but the examples I find are also hooking up a database, pulling in things, and hooking up other stuff that I don't need right now, and the documentation doesn't cover it.

Apologies for all the questions, but it saves going back and fore in the comments.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well! After a bit of fiddling, I managed to do what I wanted.

Basically, what I did was:

1) Created a Node file to serve the static files from React's `build` folder

2) Installed Node & Forever on EC2

3) Cloned my repo

4) run my Node server file with `forever`

---

## Here's how...

- Create a Node server file in the root of your React project to serve the front-end (*I called it server.js*)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}`));
```

- Spin up a default Ubuntu EC2 instance with security groups for:

  - SSH - port 20
  - HTTP - port 80
  - HTTPS - port 443
  - Custom - port 3000
- SSH in to the instance
- Install Node. These are the steps I used from AWS' pages [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html)

  - `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`
  - `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
  - `nvm install node`
  - `node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"`
- Install [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

  - `npm install -g forever`
- Clone the repo

  - `git clone my-repo.git`
- Change into the newly created directory

  - `cd my-new-directory`
- Install the project's dependencies

  - `npm i`
- Create a production version of the React project

  - `npm run build`
- Run the Node server file we created earlier

  - `forever start server.js`

---

Your site should now be up and running, with Node serving the production ready build from React's `build` folder =)

Answer (score 1):

With a static frontend I suppose you could use node, I'd probably not choose to use node for a static website.

Another option would be to install a web server on your EC2 instance like [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) or [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/). A quick google search will give you plenty of help here - something like "[nginx static website](https://medium.com/@jgefroh/a-guide-to-using-nginx-for-static-websites-d96a9d034940)".

Since you aren't running a node application PM2 doesn't really make sense. If you ever have a node backend running, you can [set up NGINX as an HTTP proxy for your node application](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/pm2-nginx-production-setup).

Comment: Thanks Andy, but as I said, the project will grow and will use Node, so future proofing it now seems apt.

Comment: IMO you would still want your static files hosted by a traditional web server like NGINX or Apache and set up a proxy for the node application.